# Locate picture details found on the Bing lock screen in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: photos, search, bing

Is it possible to get the picture info of the current Bing Lock Screen photo without going to the Bing site?

I am using a Nokia 920 and Windows Phone 8.1 OS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Settings > Lock Screen`. Underneath the `Background` option, you will see all available information for that picture. (All information available via the phone, that is.)

Comment: WP 8.1 640lte only says "photo " in lock screen setting. No other info. I've often wondered where the images are taken, its a pity that bing don't seem to have a simple facility to I.d. todays photo, rather than wade thru a vast archive!
Not that it matters much now wp is obsolete!